# Identify date/time format

Tags: date-time

I've been given some data to create some chart graphics and the dates are in a format I don't recognise. If I knew the format name I could easily look them up but initial search has drawn a blank. Example below..

```
        [1126051200000, 29.9],  '7th Sep 2005
        [1126137600000, 71.5],  '8th Sep 2005
        [1126224000000, 106.4], '9th Sep 2005
        [1126483200000, 129.2], '12th Sep 2005
        [1126569600000, 144.0], '13th Sep 2005
        [1126656000000, 176.0]  '14th Sep 2005
```

I've added the dates I know as comments but what format are these dates in? Eg how is `1126051200000` = 7th Sep 2005?

I suspect the `00000` padding is time but not used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are Unix Epoch millisecond date/time stamps. [Here](http://www.epochconverter.com) is one converter or you could always write your own. Basically it is the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970 not counting leap seconds.

Assuming you have a UNIX shell handy, they can be converted to any format using the [`date`](http://man.cx/date) tool with the argument `--date=${epoch_time}`, for example:

```
$ date --date=@1126051200.000
Wed Sep  7 02:00:00 CEST 2005
$ date --date=@1126051200.000 -u
Wed Sep  7 00:00:00 UTC 2005
$ date --date=@1126051200.000 -u -Ins
2005-09-07T00:00:00,000000000+0000
$ date --date=@1126051200.000 -u "+'%-dth %b %Y"
'7th Sep 2005
```

Inversely, you could use something like:

```
$ date --date="7 Sep 2005" -u "+%s%3N"
1126051200000
```

Comment: Seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Ooops, how right you are

Comment: No, they are most certainly milliseconds.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the fact that the time stamps in the question are Epoch milliseconds while the standard definition of Epoch Time is seconds.

Comment: I agree, while adding that the epoch timestamp is often accompanied by a us or ns timestamp in the same struct or similar. I think the first version of the answer fits the question better (as in not wrong), though. Sorry about going overboard with examples, I didn't mean to, but I'm done now.

Comment: All good. That is why answers are community editable.

Comment: I've just calulated it - it's ms for the values I posted. I think Unix Epoch time is defined as seconds but the values I have are to ms accuracy. So you're all right!